# Reload a controller not managed by ngRoute on route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

My web application login process is as follows,

a. The user clicked on the login button, and the link take them to http://localhost:3030/login/facebook

b. The NodeJS backend receives the request, and with passport-facebook, directs the browser to the Facebook login page.

c. The Facebook then direct the user back to the callback with some user data. (the callback: http://localhost:3030/login/facebook/callback)

d. With the user data, an account either exist or will be created, and a token belonging to the account will be created (with JWT)

e. That token will be sent to the user by redirection to http://localhost:3030/#/got_token/the_actual_jwt_string

f. The AngularJS application will take the route with ngRoute, and save the token in localStorage.

The Token Issue Code in NodeJS,

```
server.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {session: false}));
server.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {session: false}), function(req, res) {
  var token = jwt.sign(/* issue a token */);
  // put the token into database
  res.header('Location', 'http://localhost:3030/#/got_token/' + token);
  res.send(302);
});
```

The routing code in AngularJS,

```
.when('/got_token/:token*', {
   redirectTo: function(parameters, path, search) {
     localStorage.setItem('ngStorage-token', JSON.stringify({
       token: parameters.token
      }));
     return '/';
    }
 })
```

This works great until that my view hierarchy looks like this,

```
<body ng-controller="NavigationViewController">
  <div ng-view>
  </div>
</body>
```

And the controller code,

```
controllers.controller('NavigationViewController', ['$scope', '$route', 'token', function($scope, $route, token) {
    var _token = token.retrieve();
    $scope.token = _token;
    $scope.authenticated = (_token != '');
    if ($scope.authenticated) {
      var payload_string = b64utos(_token.split('.')[1]);
      var payload = KJUR.jws.JWS.readSafeJSONString(payload_string);
      $scope.displayName = payload.facebookDisplayName;
    } else {
      $scope.displayName = 'no';
    }
    $scope.logout = function() {
      token.clear();
    };
}]);
```

The routing done by `ngRoute` does not recreate my `NavigationViewController`, leaving the `_token` variable set to the previous state.

I need a way to have the `NavigationViewController` know that the token has changed since its not involved in routing.

Comment: Its not very clear on what you want. Do you mean `NavigationViewController` needs to know or get some event that notifies it as soon as the token changed? And when does it change? After login, why would the token change!

Comment: @Салман Yes, `NavigationViewController` needs to know. The token only changed on login/logoout, and I put the login logic in routing, logout logic in `NavigationViewController `.

Comment: Why do I think it isn't the correct, or I should say standard way of doing this? You could use ui-router and login & logout should be individual routes where as all pages that needs authentication should be a child of one or more `abstract` views. Have you deliberately taken this way or are unaware about the other?

Comment: @Салман I'm just starting to learn AngularJS, and I am not familiar with all the popular modules. Your suggestion to switch to `ui-router` is one thing I'm planning to learn, but the problem I see here isn't with routing. I'm only using routing to deliver the token back. My another application doesn't rely on Facebook, so its authentication process is a POST request, which can be done in controller. Facebook however needs a lot of work, and cannot be embedded (as far as I know) in controller alone.

Answer (score 1):

Would like to suggest you two ideas.Here are these two.
(1.) You can add $watch to the token so that whenever it would be changed it will automatically reflect.
(2.) Assign the token into rootscope and update it whenever the token gets changed.

I would like to give you the examples as well if you would needed.

Regards,
Mahendra

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to pass data between controllers. Here's a way you could do it. Listen on an event in your `NavigationViewController` for `changed` and `emit` the event it when it changes. Bind it on `rootScope`.

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.changeToken = function () {
        $rootScope.$emit('changed', +new Date());
    }
})

.controller('NavigationViewController', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.token = null;

    $rootScope.$on('changed', function(event, token) {
        $scope.token = token;
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end, a simple solution is used -- Events.

As the title of my problem suggests, I want to reload a nested parent view controller on route change. Since the parent of the nested hierarchy is not managed by `ngRoute`, it won't do it automagically. However, `ngRoute` has a service (`$route`) which emit events, and that is the simplest answer.

Basically, I put all the initialization code to a function, and call that function on event.

```
controllers.controller('NavigationViewController', ['$scope', '$route', '$location', 'token', function($scope, $route, $location, token) {
    var updateNavigationBar = function() {
      var _token = token.retrieve();
      $scope.token = _token;
      $scope.authenticated = (_token != '');
      if ($scope.authenticated) {
        var payload_string = b64utos(_token.split('.')[1]);
        var payload = KJUR.jws.JWS.readSafeJSONString(payload_string);
        $scope.displayName = payload.facebookDisplayName;
      } else {
        $scope.displayName = 'no';
      }
    };

    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current, previous) {
      if ($location.path() == '/events') {
        updateNavigationBar();
      }
    });

    updateNavigationBar();
}]);
```